# Angular2 directive visiblity

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-directives

I am rather dismayed that I can't send the visibility of a reusable directive in Angular2.

1) I have a login page

I want to sent the visibility of my navbar.  When I am on the login page then not visible then when I login then visible.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
               <navbar [visible]="isLoggedIn"></navbar>
               <div class="container"> 
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
               </div>`,
    directives: [NavbarComponent,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

In my app.component.ts I have the below set; this works, the navbar is not visible.  If a toggle between true and false it works so I know that from `app.component` it works.

```
  isLoggedIn=false;
```

In my login page I set the visibility but it does not work.

How do I talk to the navbar component to say "I need to change your visibility now because I am logged in.  I added you as a provider". Below I set this.isLoggedIn = true; when logged in but still hidden.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { contentHeaders } from '../common/headers';
import {NavbarComponent} from '../navbar/navbar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  directives: [ NavbarComponent,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES ],
  templateUrl: 'app/login/login.component.html',
  styles: [ 'app/login/login.component.css' ]
})
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(public router: Router, public http: Http) {
  }


  //visibility: hidden;

  public isLoggedIn: boolean = false;


  login(event: any, username: string, password: string) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let body = JSON.stringify({ username, password });
    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8050/auth', body, { headers: contentHeaders })
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          localStorage.setItem('id_token', response.json().access_token);
          console.log(response.json().access_token);
          console.log(this.isLoggedIn);
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
          console.log(this.isLoggedIn);
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        },
        error => {
          alert(error.text());
          console.log(error.text());
        }
      );
  } 

  signup(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.router.navigate(['/signup']);
  }
}
```

Here is my navbar.compoment.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES,Location } from '@angular/common';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router,ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: 'app/navbar/navbar.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]

})
export class NavbarComponent { 


    @Input() visible = true;

    //constructor(private _router: Router){}

    jwt: string;
    decodedJwt: string;
    response: string;
    api: string;
    //jwt_decode:any;
    constructor(private _loc:Location,private route: ActivatedRoute,
                public router: Router, public http: Http, public authHttp: AuthHttp) {
        this.jwt = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
        //this.decodedJwt = this.jwt && window.jwt_decode (this.jwt);
    }


   logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
   }




}
```

Here is my navbar.html

```html
<div *ngIf="visible">
  <div class="dashhead">
    <div class="dashhead-titles">
      <h6 class="dashhead-subtitle">Bootops</h6>
      <h3 class="dashhead-title">Role Builder</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="dashhead-toolbar">
      <span class="dashhead-toolbar-divider hidden-xs"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav nav-bordered">
    <li [class.active]="isCurrentRoute(['Environments'])"><a 
    <li><a (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: " added you as a provided." What is "you"? Where did you add it as provided?

Comment: Some dude provided ab answer but he deleted is answer.  He suggested I added  public isLoggedIn: boolean = true; to the login component.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a Plunker? I created a [basic example](https://plnkr.co/edit/3Z1PfiG65iYMnGcF73NQ?p=preview) and it works.

Comment: You have `isLoggedIn` in `LoginComponent`. I'd expect it to be in `AppComponent` because at the top you have annotation with `my-app` that contains `<navbar>`. When you change `isLoggedIn` in the `LoginComponent` it won't change the `isLoggedIn` variable in `AppComponent`, that's why it won't show I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<navbar [hidden]="!isLoggedIn"></navbar>
```

there's no `visible` [html attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_attributes.asp).

Comment: did not work.  But the use of [visible]="isLoggedIn" does work FYI.  Toggling public isLoggedIn: boolean = false; changes the visibility when used with *ngIf="visible". PS I use visible to show hide my spinner loading icon.